# How to move up/down multiple lines in visual studio code (mac)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, shortcut

## VisualStudioCode

Is there a method similar to sublime text for moving lines when the multi selector is active at the begin of each line?

[demo the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZRF9.gif)

Comment: If you select those lines you want to move, then Alt+uparrow or downarrow moves the whole selection at once.

Comment: thanks for your answer,
( _i know this tips but I hoped it was possible to do it with the active trigger without selection... :( _ )

Comment: You can select multiple lines with shift+up(or down) arrow, then move with alt+up/down. Why do you want to avoid selecting the lines ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cursor with CTRL+ALT+UP/DOWN or if you press CTRL+SHIFT+P (toggles Command Palette)  you will get the list with your key bindings.

You can check also the Cursor align extension or any other available on the VS Extension list:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yo1dog.cursor-align